# Prove if A and B are skew symmetric then A+B is skew symmetric

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification, solution-verification

If $A^T$ = $-A$ which means A is skew symmetric then prove that $(A+B)$ is also skew symmetric.

I managed to prove it like this:
$(A+B)^T$ = $A^T$+$B^T$ =$(-A+-B)$=$-(A+B)$

Therefore $(A+B)^T$=$-(A+B)$
which is skew symmetric.

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Looks good to me. However, it does depend on the fact that $(A + B)^T = A^T + B^T$, which you might or might not be allowed to use without further proof (it's not difficult to prove).

Comment: perfect, your approach is correct..that is the way to prove.